# Xamarin Forms - Scale webview to fit screen or make the webview fill the screen

Tags: webview, xamarin.forms, scale

I'm currently working on a project which is a "gif" control. It's a success but I'm stuck about scaling my "gif".. (#WebView)

```
public class Gif : WebView
{
    public interface IBaseUrl { string Get(); }

    public string GifSource
    {
        set
        {
            var html = new HtmlWebViewSource();
            html.BaseUrl = DependencyService.Get<IBaseUrl>().Get();
            html.Html = String.Format(@"<html><body><img width='{0}' src='{1}'/></body></html>", 400, value);
            SetValue(SourceProperty, html);
            this.Margin = -10;
        }
    }
}
```

I would like that this "gif" take place  over all of the screen, I mean that it could overflow the screen, it doesn't matter for me.

The problem is I tried lot of things but it still doesn't work.. The only thing which work but which is not adapted is to add the width/height param to the `<img/>` like it:

`String.Format(@"<html><body><img width='{0}' src='{1}'/></body></html>", 400, value);`

I could base myself on the screen size properties, but I need to know the size of the GIF image in that case and how can I access it?

Also, I thought about scroll programmatically to the center of the WebView but, one more time, I cannot find the way to achieve it..

Honestly, I begin to run out of idea, does someone can help me?

Thank in advance !

Comment: Did you have any luck with this?

Comment: Yep it works perfectly, https://github.com/Emixam23/XamarinByEmixam23/tree/master/Detailed%20Part/Controls/GifProject